# How to run a keyframe when transitioning to other page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

at the moment I trying to run a slide out/slide in page transition when going between pages, I have a slide in animation working using a keyframe that runs when the page loads, however I can't work out on how to run a keyframe when unloading from a page.

The keyframe I am trying to run:

```
    @keyframes transitionOut {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(1000px);
  }
}
```

From my understanding I think I need somesort of delay before loading to the new page to allow the animation to run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the pages loaded through ajax?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Not sure, the pages are loaded through netlify which I think load through ajax